# How to Use Custom Errors in Go Rpc

Tags: go, rpc

I am using the rpc package in the go standard library and I want to be able to return my custom errors with the RPC calls.

I have the custom error class below:

```
const (
    UNAVAILABLE = "unavailable"
    GETERROR    = "get-error"
    OTHER = "generic-error"
)

type CustomError struct {
    ErrorCode string
    Msg       string
}

func (e *CustomError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Error type: %s, Msg: %s", e.ErrorCode, e.Msg)
}
```

And the following RPC endpoint:

```
func (service *RpcService) Get(args *Args, reply *string) error {
    ....
    do something
    ...

    if err != nil {
        return CustomError{ErrorCode: GETERROR, Msg: ""}
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

The problem is that when I retrieve the error on the client side I get a rpc.ServerError. I tried to cast it to my custom error type but I get a panic saying `interface conversion: error is rpc.ServerError, not *CustomError`. Basically my question is: how can I propagate my custom error type from the RPC call.

Comment: You can use JSON string as error message and then decode it on the client

Answer (score 0):

The standard lib return the error as a string, `rpc.ServerError`.

So in your code the error you get from client will be something like:

```
"Error type: unavailable, Msg: "
```

If you want distinguish the error from client.Get, you could make your CustomError.Error() more simple, eg: `Unavailable: something wrong`, then you can treat it as a string.

Or you could add an extra string return value to distinguish the result.